# create action: Couldn't find object without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create obeject in controller and I pass parameter from `hidden_field` to find parent object

controller:

```
      def new
        @address = Address.new
      end

      def create
        @address = Entrepreneur.find(params[:entrepreneur_id]).addresses.build(address_params)
        if @address.save
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      private

      def address_params
        params.require(:address).permit(:region, :city, :street, :house, :building, :office)
      end
```

new.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for @address do |f|
  = f.input :region
  =f.input :city
  =f.input :street
  =f.input :house
  =f.input :building
  =f.input :office
  = f.hidden_field :entrepreneur_id, :value => 9 # 9 is for example
  =f.submit
```

My logs indicate that entrepreneur_id is passed:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ea+Vb8JA4IH4AYm4odDMvSGFJiHetR6YDDk2AH8rCmE=", "address"=>{"region"=>"", "city"=>"", "street"=>"", "house"=>"", "building"=>"", "office"=>"", "entrepreneur_id"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create Address"}
```

But I get an error `Couldn't find Entrepreneur without an ID`

What should I fix in my code? Thanks!

Comment: try adding `entrepreneur_id` to strong params `permit` in `address_params` method

Comment: @Orlando, no, he's calling param directly. But he has to attach it to the object, so use `params[:address][:enterpreneur_id]` instead

Comment: @Orlando thank you, but it's not working and I tryed it before

Comment: also in your form, you are namespacing `entrepreneur_id` to address, so instead of `params[:entrepreneur_id]` you need to use `address_params[:entrepreneur_id]`

Comment: btw using params directly defeats the purpose of strong params.

Comment: Strong params are not really necessary for searching...

Comment: @RubyRacer thnx, your solution helped me!

Comment: you can rewrite `Entrepreneur.find(params[:entrepreneur_id]).addresses.build(address_params)` to `Address.create(address_params)` given you are passing the `entrepreneur_id` in your params (anyone can change the hidden field for whatever value)

Comment: (yes, and that value will pass to strong_params too, you need validations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [Ruby Racer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399861/ruby-racer) comment I find the answer.

In controller `create` action I needed to rewrite building object like:

```
@address = Entrepreneur.find(params[:address][:entrepreneur_id]).addresses.build(address_params)
```